# Robot Framework Appium Library : Input Text from certain Coordinates or Append text to the Existing text?

Tags: appium, robotframework, python-appium

I am using RobotFramework-appium Library. There is a keyword "Input Text" to put the the text in edit text box. "Input Text" Keyword clears the existing text and starts writing the text from starting coordinates. Now my question is, Is it possible to write the text from a particular coordinates or Append text to the existing text?

Comment: As a work-around, you could retrieve the existing text, append your new text to that string variable, and send that string variable back to the text element.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the text value from the text box using the `Collections` library:

```
*** Settings ***
Library Collections

*** Keywords ****

Append Value in Text Box
  @{list}=  create list

  ${get_text}=  Get Text  id=textbox
  append to list  ${list}  ${get_text}
  ${my_text}=  InputForTextBox
  append to list  ${list}  ${my_text}
  Input Text  id=textbox   ${list}
```

More on collections library  [here](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Append%20To%20List)

Comment: Is it possible to input text from right to left instead of left to right? Also, Is it possible to input text from the middle of the text box instead of inputting from the start?

Comment: @SaiBharathReddyMallavarapu You can manipulate the test above to do most of that